# Json validation custom errors

Tags: json, scala, playframework

the following code validates the json fields against a case class. How can I add custom error messages if the name, email, address is null or if an Integer is supplied instead of a string?

```
implicit val reads: Reads[ValidateDetails] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "email").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "address").read[String])(ValidateDBConfigJson.apply _)
 }
```

I also want the custom error messages in the following json format.

```
 {
 "ErrorMessages" : 
    [
    "Error 1", 
    "Error 2"
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

After read, for each field, you can `filter` the result for the validation error. For example for the field `name`:

```
(JsPath \ "name").read[String](JsPath \"name").read[String].filter(ValidationError("The length for name should be more than 5 characters"))(_.length > 5)
```